# ¿Como cambiar la herramienta de depuracion en pycharm?

Tags: python, pycharm

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Quiero saber como hacerlo porque lo que sucedió es que de alguna manera que desconozco cambie de la herramienta de debugear predeterminada de pycharm a la de pydev debug, y no se como cambiarla a la herramienta de pycharm.
y por supuesto quiero cambiarla porque la herramienta de pycharm es mucho mejor y ya la se utilizar

Lo que sucede es que al poner los breakePoints en el editor y correr el debug (apretar el bichito al lado del boton para ejecutar el código), lo que me sale en la consola de Run es:
Connected to pydev debugger (build 213.7172.26)
y a continuación la ejecución normal del programa

y por supuesto no se ejecutan los BreakePoints del debuguer depycharm

Comment: La proxima te recomiendo editar tu pregunta anterior y allí traducirla. Ahora te recomiendo eliminar tu pregunta anterior. Gracias por traducirla!

Comment: ¿No será que la línea donde pusiste el breakpoint nunca se ejecuta? Puede que esté en un método que nunca se llama, o dentro de una condición en la que el programa nunca entra. Considera poner un ejemplo e ilustrar el problema con un miniprograma. En este caso adjuntar una imagen ayudaría.

Comment: si, la había publicado en ingles pensando que esto era stack overflow en ingles sajfdsasjsj, y ahí adjunte la imagen, si necesitan mas información avísenme, espero que halla quedado todo claro, por si no: lo que sucede es que al apretar el bichito (el boton para debugear al lado del de ejecutar) sucede eso, se abre la consola de debugueo pero con lo que sucede con el programa normalmente si no hubiera debugueado nada, dice pydev debuger al princiop, cosa que antes no sucedia y ahi se pueden ver los puntos de quiebre o breakePints que puse y aun asi no sucede nada, como desactivo o saco eso?

Comment: ocurre solamente en este proyecto

Comment: ya lo solucines, com dijo @JaimeMenéndez, esas líneas de código no se estaban ejecutando, ahí estaba el error

Comment: Bienvenido a SO Español, por favor añade el código en modo texto, y pon en respuesta la solución a tu problemas para futuros usuarios.